# How can I get continuous top and bottom borders in an html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm writing a program which will produce an html file for displaying some data.  I need all columns to be aligned, so I'm trying to use a single html table, but I want to have solid horizontal lines in between some of the rows to separate the data.  Using `border-top` and `border-bottom` I've been able to get most of the way towards what I want, however the horizontal lines that this produces aren't solid (see image).

[image: image from chrome broswer]

My questions are:

1. How can I get solid horiztonal lines between some of rows in my table
2. Also, a minor query, is there a better way of getting a bit of space between the row labels in the left hand column and the data.  Currently I'm specifying a blank column.

The html behind that image is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
    <style type="text/css">
        tr.border_top td {
            border-top:1pt solid black;
        }
        tr.border_bottom td {
            border-bottom:1pt solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor=white><b>DATA</b></p>
<table>
    <col align="left"></col>
    <col width=20></col>
    <col align="right"></col>
    <col align="right"></col>
    <col align="right"></col>
    <col align="right"></col>
    <tr class="border_top">
        <td><b>XYZ1</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.120</td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">2.280</span></td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">2.810</span></td>
        <td>3.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td><b>ABC1</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1.370</td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">1.550</span></td>
        <td>1.690</td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">1.780</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>XYZ2</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">1.900</span></td>
        <td>1.940</td>
        <td>2.050</td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">2.100</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="border_bottom">
        <td><b>ABC2</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">1.910</span></td>
        <td>1.950</td>
        <td>2.060</td>
        <td><span style="color:blue">2.100</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table row borders in HTML5 without gaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315070/table-row-borders-in-html5-without-gaps)

Comment: something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/kmHmK/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the CSS add the remove the default `border-spacing` and add `padding` to the cells

```
table { border-spacing:0 }
td { padding:10px; }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SWWuK/1/)

Comment: cellpadding and cellspacing are deprecated properties.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful :-).  But `td { padding:10px; }` seems to adds padding left, right, above and below. How can I just add padding to the left and right?

Comment: For left and right padding only, do `padding:0 10px`, that means `top` and `bottom` 0 and `left` and `right` get `10px` of padding.

Answer (score 2):

Give your table a class, for example `mytable`.
Then in your CSS do:

```
.mytable {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.mytable td {
 padding: .2em;
}
```

The `collapse` makes the space between cells go away and therefore makes a continuous border, like you asked for. However, then all the texts are very close together, so a little padding on the cells makes it look nicer.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful :-). But `td { padding: .2em; }` seems to adds padding left, right, above and below. How can I just add padding to the left and right?

Comment: Like this: `td { padding: 0 .2em; }` Means: 0 for top and bottom, and .2em for left and right.

Comment: Thx vm for your help :-).  I upvoted you, but the other guy got there first so I accepted his answer!

Comment: @Stochastically Cheers for that, I added my answer because Nick's initial answer was different (something with cellspacing and cellpadding) and I believed my answer to be better. Afterwards I think he changed his answer. Anyway, you should accept the answer that you have actually implemented in your project as therefore the acceptance on Stackoverflow represents real world best practice.